# Get logged variables in Robot Framework and Pabot

Tags: robotframework

In my RF tests in few places I have added logging by

```
log to console     Scanning first UID   ${pack_uids}[0]
```

But when I open HTML log file, I expected to see a value, which was used in this test. Instead I have exactly the text.

[image]

While Robot Framework can work with `${pack_uids}[0]` stored as a variable, how can I get variable value, instead of plain text? I tried also to use `Log` only, same issue.

Similar case, when I try to log to file from Python file by running

```
logger.console("Some foo")
```

But as a result, this is not presented in `log.html` file at all.

And a side question, is it possible to get logs produced by each pabot thread in some file, like it's created in the console when running a single `robot` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I found it out just after placing the question... It's really important to have `Log` only, and the details are presented in a new line

[image]

In Python file use

```
logger.write("Log you want to include" + str(variable))
```

And it's working all fine. Just mind you need to expand the logging row

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the loglevel to INFO

In the command line use --loglevel option or the Set Log Level keyword